# $n$-in-arithmetic-progression: a maker-breaker game

Tags: game-theory, ramsey-theory

Consider a 2-player game where the players take turns claiming an integer from $1$ to $n$. The same integer cannot be claimed twice. Player 1 wins if the set of integers he claims contains an arithmetic progression of $\ge k$ terms; player 2 wins if this is prevented by the time all available numbers have been claimed.

Unless I'm missing something fundamental,  for every $k$ there is $s(k)$ such that P2 wins for every $n<s(k)$ and P1 wins for every $n\ge s(k)$. I wonder: are the explicit values of $s(k)$, or at least any good asymptotics, known?

**What I have so far:**

Trivially, $s(1)=1$ and $s(2)=3$. I was also able to show that $s(3)\le12$, $s(4)\le30$ and $s(5)\le225$, by comparison to $m,n,k$-games. I expect $s(5)$ to be significantly smaller, though. For $k\ge6$, comparisons to $m,n,k$-games cease to be helpful.

In general, the number of winning sets is equal to: $w:=tn-\frac{t^2+t}2(k-1)$, where $t=\lfloor\frac n{k-1}\rfloor$. As proven by Erdős and Selfridge, if $w<2^{k-1}$ then P2 has a winning strategy. Conversely, if $w>2^{k-4} \cdot(k^2-k) \cdot n$ then P1 has a winning strategy (however, this bound can possibly be improved).

Those bounds aren't particularly heplful, though. For instance, they yield $101\le s(10)\le103690$.

**As a side note:**

Unless some clever general strategy can be found, I expect the game to actually be quite fun for $100 \le n \le 200$, especially if balanced by choosing a good value of $k$ (no less than $10$ to be sure) and introducing some kind of pie rule!

EDIT: $s(k)>2^\frac k2 \sqrt{k-1}$ will hold for large enough $k$s.

EDIT2: $s(3)=5$

EDIT3: a friend of mine was able to prove $s(4)=15$ with a computer search.

EDIT4: the upper bounds I initially provided were wrong.

Comment: Seems to me Player 1 wins $k=3$ even for $n$ as small as $8$. Player 1 chooses $5$; if Player 2 chooses $3$ then P_1 chooses $6$, threatening $4$ and $7$; if $P_2$ chooses $4$, $P_1$ chooses $7$, threatening $3$ and $6$; if $P_2$ chooses $6$, $P_1$ chooses $3$, threatening $1$, $4$, and $7$; for any other choice by $P_2$, $P_1$ chooses $4$, threatening $3$ and $6$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- $8$ doesn't seem to come up anywhere in your reasoning, so I think even $n=7$ should be a P1 win?

Comment: Yes, Michał, you're right.

Comment: It turns out even $n=5$ suffices if $k=3$. P1 chooses $3$. If P2 chooses $1$, $4$ creates a double threat. If P2 chooses $2$, $5$ creates a double threat. If P2 chooses $4$, $1$ creates a double threat. If P2 chooses 5, $2$ creates a double threat. Of course if $n=4$ then $k=3$ is trivially won by P2, and thus $s(3)=5$

Comment: What's a pie rule?

Comment: @Karl -- do excuse my jargon. The term "pie rule" refers to a class of balancing protols in games by allowing one player to swap places with the other at some point, thus incentivising a balanced opening. The most typical version allows the second player to swap places after the first move. This is the rule used in Hex, for example.